# Создать вариативный массив в зависимости от значений

Tags: php

Передаю в PHP-файл json-массив, в котором одно из полей имеет значение true или false. В зависимости от тех данных, которые отправил серверу пользователь. И если это поле - true, то при создании массива должен добавиться ещё один элемент. Но PHP ругается, что он ожидает символ `)`, а не `if` - `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')'`. Как это можно исправить с минимально возможным количеством кода, не создавая два условия и по одной и той же переменной в каждом из них?

```
$post_data = array (
    "signature" => $signature,
    "marker" => "65059",
    "host" => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
    "user_ip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    "locale" => "ru",
    "trip_class" => ($data['is_business'] == 'true' ? 'Y' : 'C'),
    "passengers" => array(
        "adults" => $data['adults'],
        "children" => $data['teens'],
        "infants" => $data['kids'],
    ),
    "segments" => array(
        0 => array(
            "origin" => $data['from'],
            "destination" => $data['to'],
            "date" => $data['there'],
        ),
        if($data['is_oneway'] == 'true') {
            1 => array(
                "origin" => $data['to'],
                "destination" => $data['from'],
                "date" => $data['thence'],
            ),
        }
    ),
);
```

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что можете взять и написать оператор `if` посреди объявления массива?

Comment: после того как вы сформировали свой массив `$post_data = [ ...];` проверьте свое условие `if($data['is_oneway] == 'true'){ ....}` и внутри него добавьте нужные данные `$post_data['segments][] = ['origin'  => ...  ]`

Answer (score 3):

```
$post_data=[
             'signature' => $signature
            ,'marker' => 65059
            ,'host' => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
            ,'user_ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
            ,'locale' => 'ru'
            ,'trip_class' => ($data['is_business'] == 'true' ? 'Y' : 'C')
            ,'passengers' => [
                                 'adults' => $data['adults']
                                ,'children' => $data['teens']
                                ,'infants' => $data['kids']
                             ]
            ,'segments' => [
                                [
                                    'origin' => $data['from']
                                    ,'destination' => $data['to']
                                    ,'date' => $data['there']
                                ]
                            ]
            ];
if($data['is_oneway'] == 'true') $post_data['segments'][]=[
                                                            'origin' => $data['to']
                                                            ,'destination' => $data['from']
                                                            ,'date' => $data['thence']
                                                            ];
```

Я все таки не соглашусь с замечаниями @Firepro

```
if ($data['is_business']=='true')
```

и

```
if ($data['is_business'])
```

совсем не одно и тоже

вы путаете это с

```
if ($data['is_business']==true)
```

Comment: дак и написали бы это в комментарии?

Comment: Да, немного поторопился в ответе. Спасибо. Булево значение конечно лучше передавать в правильном формате, а не строкой. +

Answer (score 1):

Запрещено внутри объявления массива использовать управляющие конструкции.

**Замечания:**

1) Переходите на короткий синтаксис массивов, это удобнее. Конструкцию array() можно заменить на [ ]

2) Конструкцию `if ($data['is_business']=='true')`, можно просто заменить на  `if ($data['is_business'])`, это удобнее, при условии того, что у вас передается тип bool. Передавайте булево значение из интерфейса в правильном формате во избежание различных проблем с конвертацией параметров.

3) Начните писать код по стандартам PSR, используйте camelCase для именования переменных, названий методов и т.д.

**Решение вашего вопроса:**

```
$postData = [
        "signature" => $signature,
        "marker" => 65059,
        "host" => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
        "user_ip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        "locale" => "ru",
        "trip_class" => $data['is_business'] ? 'Y' : 'C',
        "passengers" => [
            "adults" => $data['adults'],
            "children" => $data['teens'],
            "infants" => $data['kids'],
        ],
        "segments" => [
            0 => [
                "origin" => $data['from'],
                "destination" => $data['to'],
                "date" => $data['there'],
            ]
        ],
    ];

if ($data['is_oneway']) {
        $postData['segments'][] = [
                "origin" => $data['to'],
                "destination" => $data['from'],
                "date" => $data['thence'],
        ];
 }
```

Подробнее о работе массивов в PHP, [читайте на официальном сайте](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php)

Comment: По поводу первого и третьего пункта: зачем? Мне удобнее так, как написано у меня. К тому же, не думаю, что этот способ прибавит к производительности. У меня проект пока что маленький, но потом кода станет в разы больше и код станет трудно читать. Что касается булевого значения, то оно передаётся сперва в виде json-массива(где значение - булево), а потом декодируется в PHP при помощи `json_decode()` и вроде бы как становится строкой. Я уже начинаю с jQuery путать(там тоже таким способом проверяется булево значение переменной, но так надёжней)

Comment: Если в json передано значение, как {"value": bool}, при конвертации оно будет не строкой, а типом bool, при json_decode. Ну camelCase, короче на 1 байт :D Насчет 3 - это просто принятые стандарты PSR в PHP и выбор многих фреймворков (напр. Symfony), желательно чтобы все было в одном формате, меньше путаницы. Насчет этих пунктов я спорить не буду, Вы сами можете выбирать как вам удобнее писать, обсуждать это, как спорить о том, есть ли курицу руками :)